# Why the function seed returns this problem: unused argument (seed = 12345)?

Tags: r, split, h2o, seed

I am trying to split the data into training, validation, and test sets, with the h2o package, following the code in this link: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/09/hr-analytics-using-machine-learning-to-predict-employee-turnover/.

Running this code:

```
split_h2o <- h2o.splitFrame(DatiRev_h2o, c(0.7, 0.15), seed = 12345 )
```

It returns the following error : "Error in h2o.splitFrame(DatiRev_h2o, c(0.7, 0.15), seed = 12345) :
unused argument (seed = 12345)".

Can someone please explain why?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What does `args(h2o.splitFrame)` return for you?

Comment: function (data, ratios = 0.75, destination_frames) 
NULL

Comment: What version of the `h2o` package are you using? That function signature doesn't match the [official documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/h2o/man/h2o.splitFrame.html). Does that function show up under `conflicts(detail = TRUE)`?

Comment: "http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-simons/7/R"

Comment: I know it is not the official. How can I download the official one?

Comment: That seems to be a very old version of the package, like from 2015. Install the latest with `install.packages("h2o")`

Comment: It returns the same message: "Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘h2o’ failed". That's why I chose to install the oldest one.

Comment: The same message as what? Is the only message you see "download of package ‘h2o’ failed"? Are you sure you are properly connected to the internet? Can you access CRAN directly (https://cran.rstudio.com/)?

Comment: I wanted to say: "The following message". I am connected to the internet and I can access the CRAN

Comment: See http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#install-in-r for how to install the latest H2O directly. (Those instructions also make sure you don't have an old version hanging around.)

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce the error.  Are you sure that's the exact code that produced the error?  It looks like it's picking up an extra `(` somehow (maybe you had a typo and then you fixed it?).

Here's the same code, as a reproducible example (which is working):

```
library(h2o)

h2o.init()

hf <- as.h2o(iris)
split_h2o <- h2o.splitFrame(hf, c(0.7, 0.15), seed = 12345)
```

Comment: The brakets are not extras. Maybe the problem could be that, since the function DatiRev_h2o <- as.h2o(DatiRev) provides this error "Provided column type c("ordered", "enum") is unknown" I have tried to use the function "localH2O <- h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, startH2O = TRUE) #sets up the cluster

pathToData <- paste0(normalizePath("~/Downloads/"), "/dat.csv")
write.table(x = dat, file = pathToData, row.names = F, col.names = T)
dat_h2o <- h2o.importFile(path = pathToData, destination_frame = "dat")" but I don't know if it is ok (https://www.xspdf.com/help/50383257.html)